# How to count directories and get the largest numeric value

Tags: perl

I want to extract values from music structure directories using File::Find::Rule and I'm having difficulties getting the total discs of each album if present, e.g if an album contains 3 subdirectories DISC1, DISC2, DISC3 - the total discs value should be 3. If I grep these directories before the "For" statement it gets the total of all found, and if I try within the "For" statement it counts one at a time. How to extract total discs for each album if present. Thanks.

```
use autodie;
use strict; 
use warnings;
use File::Find::Rule;
use File::Spec;

my $dir = 'D:\Test';
$dir =~ s#\\#/#g;

my @fd = File::Find::Rule->directory()
->name( qr/\(\d+\)/ )
->in( $dir );

my $grep_totaldiscs = grep /DISC\d+/, @fd;
print "$grep_totaldiscs\n";

for my $fd ( @fd ) {

    my ($genre, $artist, $album, $disc) = (File::Spec->splitdir($fd))[2..5];

    my ($discnumber, $totaldiscs);
    if ($fd =~ /DISC(\d+)/) {
        $discnumber = $1;
            $totaldiscs = $1 if ( defined($totaldiscs) < $1 );
        print "$album $totaldiscs\n";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In outline:

- Before the loop: declare a hash to hold the maximum - i.e. total disc number - for each album.
- Inside the loop: update the hash entry for the album, if it is a new maximum for that one.
- After the loop: iterate over the hash to process or display.

I've used artist and album combined to disambiguate in the keys of the hash here.

For example:

```
my %album_discs;
for my $fd ( @fd ) {

    my ($genre, $artist, $album, $disc) = (File::Spec->splitdir($fd))[2..5];
    my $aakey = "${artist}~${album}";

    my ($discnumber, $totaldiscs);
    if ($fd =~ /DISC(\d+)/) {
        $discnumber = $1;
        $album_discs{$aakey} = $discnumber
            if ( ! exists $album_discs{$aakey} || $album_discs{$aakey} < $discnumber );
    }
}

for my $aakey ( keys %album_discs ) {
    my ( $artist, $album ) = split( /~/, $aakey );
    print "Number of discs for album $album by $artist is $album_discs{$aakey}\n";
}
```

Comment: Martin, many thanks for your assistance. I tested your suggestion and it prints all found directories containing disc number but with value 1. I'm not good with hash keys to see if anything should be corrected but I'll continue testing.

Comment: I think I had the `if` the wrong way round - that might have been part of the problem.  Now corrected.